# ProtocolConnectionException in the context of Python versions

Tags: php, python, sockets, networking, sublimetext2

I'm totally unfamiliar with Python but I there is a piece of code that I need to fix. It's from [SublimeXdebug](https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug) plugin for Sublime Text 2, which is the only plugin out there for PHP debugging with Sublime Text. The plugin is written in Python and, more specifically, in Python 2.6 or older, while the system the plugin runs on (Ubuntu 12.04) only supports Python >= 2.7. However, it seems that the plugin / Sublime Text developers somehow managed to "emulate" Python 2.6 because when I insert `print sys.version` into the plugin's code, it reports `Python 2.6.6`. It could have helped some other plugins but not SublimeXdebug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File ".\threading.py", line 484, in run
  File "./Xdebug.py", line 321, in thread_callback
    protocol.accept()
  File "./Xdebug.py", line 137, in accept
    raise(ProtocolConnectionException, x)
ProtocolConnectionException
```

and the problematic piece of code (probably not the only one) goes like this:

```
def accept(self):
    serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    if serv:
        try:
            serv.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            serv.settimeout(1)
            serv.bind(('', self.port))
            serv.listen(1)
            self.listening = True
            self.sock = None
        except Exception, x:
            raise(ProtocolConnectionException, x) # line 137 <------------

        while self.listening:
            try:
                self.sock, address = serv.accept()
                self.listening = False
            except socket.timeout:
                pass

        if self.sock:
            self.connected = True
            self.sock.settimeout(None)
        else:
            self.connected = False
            self.listening = False

        try:
            serv.close()
            serv = None
        except:
            pass
        return self.sock
    else:
        raise ProtocolConnectionException('Could not create socket')
```

(For those who would recommend downloading a 2.6 version of Python in a .deb, unpacking it, and then moving `usr/lib/python2.6` into `{sublime text folder}/lib`, I tried it already, didn't help.)

So could the root of the problem be in Python version mismatch or something else?

*Edit:*

If I change the line 137 to just `raise` it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File ".\threading.py", line 484, in run
  File "./Xdebug.py", line 321, in thread_callback
  File "./Xdebug.py", line 132, in accept
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

The line 132 is `serv.bind(('', self.port))`.

Comment: They don't need to "emulate" Python 2.6. Sublime Text probably just bundles its own "clean" private installation of Python instead of depending on the system-provided one. So the error you're seeing might not be caused by a Python version mismatch.

Comment: Are you sure something is "emulating" Python 2.6, and not actually just using 2.6 for real? What is `sys.executable`? Also, what happens if you change that `raise(Protocol....)` on line 137 to just `raise`? This will raise the original exception (as if there were no try: except: block at all), and we will be able to see what the problem really was.

Comment: @PhilFrost Yes, I checked it, the installed version is 2.7, `/usr/lib/python2.6` folder is almost empty, unlike `/usr/lib/python2.7`, which looks like a full-fledged family of Python files and folders. And `sys.executable` only appears once on this Stack Overflow page, in your comment :)

Comment: @PhilFrost Updated the question to quote the output it produces if the line is `raise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this Python version stuff is a red herring. What's happening is this code is attempting to listen on a TCP port (whatever `self.port` is), but something else is already listening there. On Linux, you could run `sudo netstat -anp | grep LISTEN` to figure out what process that is.